# Which c3p0 properties I need to use for hibernate pooling?

Tags: hibernate, c3p0, hibernate.cfg.xml

Which c3p0 properties I must use for Hibernate Configuration?

My configuration is as follow:

```
 <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
 <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
 <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
 <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
 <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>
```

What are necessary properties and correct values I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

The most important c3p0 that your application may work with it properly is as follows:

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">5</property>
<property name ="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">3600</property>
<property name ="hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTimeExcessConnections">300</property>
<property name ="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">200</property>
<property name ="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">20</property>
<property name ="hibernate.c3p0.numHelperThreads">6</property>
<property name ="hibernate.c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout">3600</property>
<property name ="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">1000</property>
```

Comment: Thank you. But what values should I use? and if I'll use these properties will it cause of slow performance?  Cause profiler shows it takes much memory but other answers says shouldn't be worried about it.

Comment: I provided this configuration since I used it in my enterprise mid-size application. If you need to know meaning and details of each entry, you need to read the c3p0 documentation.

Comment: I don't know about values, I'll read the documentation. Thank you so much